# Hot check if one QueryString Variable is not Used in url having muitliple Querystring variables

Tags: c#, asp.net

For Example my url are
`1- newz4online.com/News_details?News=asdfffffff`
`2- newz4online.com/News_details?BNews=asssss`

Now News_details is a single page, but Using those 2 different querystring variables i am get different values using some if else conditions. So for that i need to check that weather which variable is there and which is not.

```
string newz = Request.QueryString["News"];
string BNews = Request.QueryString["BNews"];
```

these are the method for getting the value from the querystring
if the url would like

`newz4online.com/News_details?News=asdfffff&BNews=
and newz4online.com/News_details?News=&BNews=asssss`

but it is used when a variable is there,

if there is no variable then it dont gives any value,
`newz4online.com/News_details?News=asdfffffff`

2- `newz4online.com/News_details?BNews=asssss`

it will give only single variable value which is used.

What i am asking that how can i do this if a url have one querystring variable and have no other so that i can assign other variable to null..?

Please help me in this

Answer (score 0):

If the particular QueryString isn't there, the string in your assignment will already by null. Just be sure to check for null before trying to use them both. See the explanation of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) example.

Alternatively, you can try this, and then just check for empty strings

```
string newz = ( Request.QueryString["News"] == null ? "" : Request.QueryString["News"] );
string Bnewz = ( Request.QueryString["BNews"] == null ? "" : Request.QueryString["BNews"] );
```